# How to bind string property to TextBox within ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

I'm binding a `List<string>` to my `ListBox` in WPF using MVVM

At the moment I have

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileContents}"></ListBox>
```

File Contents in my ViewModel is simply

```
public List<string> FileContents {get;set;}
```

And the FileContents values are set in the constructor of the ViewModel, as such there is no need to worry about INotifyProperty

Everything works fine so far. I can see the list displayed in my `ListBox` as desired.

Now I need to provide a template! This is where it goes wrong

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding FileContents}">
     <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <TextBox Text="{Binding}" />
           </DataTemplate>
     </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
 </ListBox>
```

This is where it all goes wrong! My understanding is that I only need to do `<TextBox Text = "{Binding}"` because the ListBox is already bound to the `List<string>` property (called FileContents)

However, when I run the above Visual Studio gives me

> The application is in break mode

If I update the code to

`<TextBox Text = "Some String Value"`

then it works fine

I don't understand what I've done wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `Mode` of the `Binding` to `OneWay`:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=., Mode=OneWay}" />
```

The default binding mode for the `Text` property of a `TextBox` is `TwoWay` but this won't work when you bind to a `string` in a `List<string>`.

Answer (score 2):

Binding to a `string` directly is only possible one way. This means you are only able to bind read only like

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

or

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding .}"/>
```

**The reason** is simple: Changing the string means you are removing and adding an item to your list. This is simply not possible by changing the string in a TextBox.

**A solution** is to wrap the content in a class like

```
public class FileContent
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

and bind to a list of `List<FileContent>` by using `<TextBox Text="{Binding Content}"/>` as template.